# Energy of Magnetic Dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, magnetic-moment

What is the total energy of a magnetic dipole, $\textbf{m}$, in the presence of a magnetic field $\textbf{H}_s$?

I've seen the typical answer given is:

$U = - \textbf{m}.\textbf{B}\Delta_v + U_s$

Where $\Delta_v$ is the volume over which the dipole exists and $U_s$ is the energy of the source field. However, no one seems to state what $\textbf{B}$ is, it seems to be implied that $\textbf{B} = \mu_0 \textbf{H}_s$.

However, I've also seen written that the total energy of a magnetic system is:

$U = \frac{1}{2}\int \textbf{H}.\textbf{B} \: \:dv$

However, as the magnetic dipole creates its own magnetic field, $\textbf{H}_m$, then the total $\textbf{H}$ and $\textbf{B}$ are given by:

$\textbf{H} = \textbf{H}_s + \textbf{H}_m$

and

$\textbf{B} = \mu_0\textbf{H}_s + \mu_0\textbf{H}_m +\mu_0\textbf{m}$

note that $\textbf{H}_m = 0$ at the position of $\textbf{m}$.

Then the total energy is given by:

$U = \frac{\mu_0}{2}\int \textbf{H}_s.\textbf{H}_s + 2\textbf{H}_s.\textbf{H}_m + \textbf{H}_m.\textbf{H}_m + \textbf{H}_s.\textbf{m} \: \:\textrm{d}v$

This doesn't appear to give the usual result $U = - \textbf{m}.\textbf{B}\Delta_v + U_s$.

I have the source term:
$U_s = \frac{\mu_0}{2}\int \textbf{H}_s.\textbf{H}_s \: \:\textrm{d}v$

and 2 terms that require the calculation of the dipole field and a POSITIVE contribution to the energy from a parallel dipole:

$\Delta U = \frac{\mu_0}{2}\int 2\textbf{H}_s.\textbf{H}_m + \textbf{H}_m.\textbf{H}_m + \textbf{H}_s.\textbf{m} \: \:\textrm{d}v$

I can't see why this would give the simple result...

Even if we say that the dipole field is weak compared to the source field, which doesn't have to be true at all, we're still out by a factor of -2...

If anyone could help me marry up these two results I'd be very grateful!

Thanks

Comment: The two results will not agree because when you use $\mathbf{H}\cdot\mathbf{B}/2$ you are also taking into account the (positive) self energy of the dipole, i.e., $(\mathbf{B}_\text{dip})^2$. This term is specifically ignored in $-\mathbf{m}\cdot\mathbf{B}$.

Comment: Thanks for this. That deals with 1 term. What about the the other 2 and that fact that a parallel dipole appears to cost energy (m.H gives a positive integrand)?